# Why should i create a customer object before charging in stripe?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Hi i have seen the code for stripe payment as below. First create a customer object

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
          "card" => $token,
          "description" => "Product Purchase for Book",
          "email" => "someone@example.com"
 ));
```

Then charge by using that customer object

```
  \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
         "amount" => $amount, # amount in cents, again
         "currency" => 'usd',
         "customer" => $customer->id)
   );
```

But below is the code which can be used to charge the user directly without creating any customer object.

```
\Stripe\Charge::create(array(
       "amount" => 3000,
       "currency" => "eur",
       "card" => $_POST['stripeToken'],
       "description" => $_POST['email'],
       "metadata" => array("order_id" => "6735", "userid" => '1111')
));
```

So can you please explain me below things

1. Which one is better?
2. What is the benefit of creating a customer object?
3. Can use store and use that customer object to charge that user any any time say recurring payment?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several benefits to creating the customer object first:

1. You can charge multiple items to the same user, thus providing both you and the customer a billing history. This is valuable to you as a store owner (e.g. offering deals to repeat customers) and valuable to the customer to quickly pull up their purchase history.
2. Fraud prevention
3. Trends and analytics
4. As you've already stated, subscriptions

A footnote: I personally maintain my own user-base and update both the Stripe customer object and my user data when a transaction occurs. This allows me to extend the Stripe customer with my own custom data and run complex analytics to discover trends.

Comment: Thanks @brandonscript for quick response. But stripe provide a concept called **plan** for recurring payment. Should i use that or write code like a cron job to charge that user at the end of a period say at the end of the month?

Comment: No no -- **definitely** use plan. It's just that by creating the customer object on the first transaction (single or subscription), it's then a lot easier to take the same customer and subscribe them to a plan. If you don't create a customer, then you have to wire all the transactions together somehow elsewhere. Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: So should we store the token in the database for later use?

Comment: No, token is a one-time generated security token to ensure the transaction is validated. Highly recommend you read their docs top to bottom -- probably the best damn API docs I've ever seen.

Comment: Ok. Thank you again